# Use MySQLi in classes, how to implement?

Tags: php, database, oop, mysqli

Till now I passed the `$database`-object through an argument in the `__constructor`
But I want to get rid of passing it through in every class. But how to do it? I'm not a very smart OOP-er, I know some basics though...
Here's my code I use now: **UPDATED**

```
class connection {
    public static $connection;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->connection = new MySQLi('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
        $this->connection->select_db('database');
    }

    public function getInstance() {
        if(!isset(self::$connection)) {
            self::$connection = new connection;
        }
        return self::$connection;
    }
}

class something {
    private $connection;

    public $id;

    function __construct($id) {
        $this->connection = connection::getInstance();
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    function verify() {
        $statement = $this->connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM `tabel` WHERE `id` = ?');
        $statement->bind_param('s', $this->id);
        $statement->execute();

        $statement->store_result();
        if($statement->num_rows != 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**It doesn't work: `Call to undefined method connection::prepare()`**

Comment: Well, you need to get the database in there somehow. Either you pass it in, or your class needs to get the connection itself. If you're going to have the class get the connection itself, wrap it in a singleton so you can do something like `DBManager::getConnection()`, perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MySQLi::getInstance($optional_instance_name)` as a static method that retrieves whatever database connection you ask for.

Comment: Eahh, if I put that in the constructor it says `Call to undefined method mysqli::getinstance()` Don't forget I'm not an expert in OOP...xD

Comment: It was sort of implicit in my answer, but you'll need to build that method. Take a look at the singleton patterns listed here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php (you don't want a true singleton, but rather a registry that returns or initializes whatever instances you requested)

Comment: Aside from that, read up on OOP. Your code is going to be garbage until you have a good grasp of the concepts.

Comment: @Kenaniah: just because you called that code garbage: singletons are often considered no better than global variables.  So much so that they are often considered an [Anti-Pattern](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/337)...  And what you're describing is really a [Multiton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern)...  Stick with dependency injection, it's the better solution...

Comment: Multiton. That's the word I was looking for :-). @ircmaxell, singletons generally are garbage. That said, when dealing with a persistent resource that's not likely to ever change (a good number of apps only operate on a single database), it's generally easier to reconfigure your singleton/multitions than it is to manage injected dependencies. Since it's a DB connection, I'm taking the pragmatic approach. But if your objects need to operate on multiple databases, dependency injection wins.